# require_once writes "1" to source code

Tags: php

I'm new to PHP and trying to include a file in another with the following code:

```
<?= require_once ('../template/header.phtml')?>
```

The inclusion works, but it also adds a "1" to the source code. Same happens if I use include() include_once() or require(). Got no results searching the web as well.

Comment: use `<?`  instead of `<?=`.

Comment: @Sirko then the files won't be included

Comment: `<?=` will echo the result returned by the `require_once()` which will be a Boolean true if successful, and the require() doesn't explicitly return a value or echo anything, so that Boolean true will be displayed as `1`

Comment: Use `<?` as @Sirko said. That will include the file, but not display the boolean true result of the `require`

Comment: @kvothe try with `<?php` - see my answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `<?=` instead of `<?php` to start your script. `<?=` is used to print something to the screen, which in this case is the return value from `require_once ('../template/header.phtml')`, which most likely is `TRUE` ie. `1`. Change the opening tag and your problem should go away.

The correct place to use `<?=` is when you just want to print a variable or a function's return value in the middle of html, like so:

```
<div>
    <?=$some_variable?>
</div>
```

Comment: require_once returns true if file is already imported. Also returns true if (echo)ed when file is present

Answer (score 1):

You should use `<?php require_once ('../template/header.phtml')?>`